# Нужна ли запятая между прямой речью и союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, союзы

*Если вы хотите, спросите его: "Когда я могу подойти?" и предупредите нас о своём приходе.*

Нужна ли запятая перед своюзом "и"?

Answer (score 4):

Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то она заключается в кавычки, перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после – тире:

*Она вскрикнула: «Ай, не он, не он!» – и упала без памяти* (Пушкин).
 [**Знаки препинания в предложениях с прямой речью**](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)

В Вашем предложении "*Если вы хотите, спросите его... и предупредите нас о* *своём приходе*" - это слова автора, которые сами по себе тоже являются прямой речью.
Правильная пунктуация будет такая:

***—Если вы хотите, спросите его: "Когда я могу подойти?"— и предупредите нас о своём приходе.***
Или:
 ***«Если вы хотите, спросите его: "Когда я могу подойти?"— и предупредите нас о своём приходе».***

**Дополнение** (примеры)

*—Мне физкультурник орал: "Александрова, что вы на него лезете, как куль с мякиной?!" И все смеялись. И ты тоже смеёшься!..*
[**Т.Устинова, Вселенский заговор**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=KKTbCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=%D0%A2%20%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9?!&source=bl&ots=NBqYM2e8qx&sig=zi0WXYqmNVUyv5EGA_1Ic0iw4mc&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiluY_Xqq7UAhXGO5oKHXPfDM0Q6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%20%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%3F!&f=false)

*Солнце светило, где-то трактор гудел, стучал мяч, мальчишки вопили восторженно: "Е-есть!", и радио пело длинную песню.*
[**Т.Устинова, Вселенский заговор**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=KKTbCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&lpg=PT167&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C!&source=bl&ots=NBqYM2g9qp&sig=l7nDxwbpm9wiwPWO1YwdPyWJaD4&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilpue8sq7UAhXsA5oKHXNLDEEQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C!&f=false)
В этом случае после прямой речи - перед "и" - запятая ставится.

Comment: Римма Михайлова, слова автора как могут быть прямой речью. Что-то я не понимаю.

Comment: Диалог между Марусей и Гришей: --Мне физкультурник орал: "Александрова, что вы на него лезете, как куль с мякиной?!" И все смеялись. И ты тоже смеёшься!.. (Т.Устинова, "Вселенский заговор")  Маруся рассказывает, и внутри её слов - чужие: т.н. прямая речь внутри прямой речи. Сейчас в ответе дам ссылку, здесь не "влезает".

Answer (score 2):

**Если (вы) хотите, спросите его: "Когда я могу подойти?"  —  и предупредите нас о своём приходе.**

Нет знаков препинания на месте разрыва слов автора (ставится тире).

Розенталь: …Она сказала: «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку (Л. Т.) — тире перед союзом И при однородных сказуемых. [§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159)

Answer (score 0):

Если "спросите" и "предупредите" относится к одному придаточному (оба эти действия выполняются по условию "хотите", то запятая не нужна, и в силу вступает правило о тире между прямой речью и речью автора.
Если же "хотите" относится только к первому действию "спросить", то это разные предложения, придаточное заканчивается на прямой речи, запятая обязательна и тире а таком случае не требуется - его использование меняло бы грамматику фразы.

Comment: После восклицательного и вопросительного знаков тире ставится для обозначения соответствующей интонации. Розенталь:И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто легче (Ч.) — тире после вопросительного/восклицательного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь. Сравнить: Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», но глаза его блестят, полные зависти.

Comment: @Sibylla я знаю. Только не "после знаков", а после кавычки. И не вместо запятой.

Comment: Это цитаты из Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Comment: @Sibylla Я об этом: "После восклицательного и вопросительного знаков тире ставится для обозначения соответствующей интонации."  У Розенталя  этих слов нет. И быть не может.

Comment: У меня Розенталь начинается после двоеточия. А  до этого идут общие рассуждения на тему, Розенталь нам ведь не рассказывает, почему ставится тире.  Без паузы не выразить вопрос или восклицание, то есть прямая речь получается встроенной, не имеющей свою интонацию.

Comment: @Sibylla  а говорю о том, что у вас **до двоеточия**. Рассуждения не очень интересуют, но вы делаете фактическую ошибку. Вот ваша фраза: "После восклицательного и вопросительного знаков тире ставится" - в ней ошибка. **Тире ставится не после знака, а после кавычки.**  И не вместо запятой. И вообще все это никаким образом к моему ответу не относится.